# Configuring email - when i send out email they all come from ACCOUNT@www.mydomain.com instead of ACCOUNT@domain.com. Is this an alias problem?

Tags: email-server, mac-osx-server, nameserver, domain-name, accounts

Configuring email - when i send out email they all come from ACCOUNT@www.mydomain.com instead of ACCOUNT@domain.com. Is this an alias problem?

Do i need to configure my dns or mail server in a certain way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [New Mac OS X Server setup, when i send mail to gmail it goes straight to Spam. Why is that?](http://serverfault.com/questions/218115/new-mac-os-x-server-setup-when-i-send-mail-to-gmail-it-goes-straight-to-spam-wh)

Comment: Not really. This has something to do with domain names only. It is true that a bad setup can lead to email problems too.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you have not set up aliases, I am unsure how to to this on a mac but basically you need to alias ACCCOUNT@domain.com to ACCOUNT@www.domain.com. An alternative approach would be to change the hostname of the system to remove the WWW.

Hope that helps, 
RayQuang

Answer (score 0):

The problem is incorrect settings in the Mail settings, General pane:

Correct settings should be:

```
domain name: example.com
host name: mail.example.com
```